# Can't map grouped array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I grouped an array using reduce. But I can't list array with map function. It says .map is not a function.

```
const grouped = courses.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => ({
   ...objectsByKeyValue,
   [obj['date']]: (objectsByKeyValue[obj['date']] || []).concat(obj)
}), {});

      setCourses(grouped)
```

It's grouping the array like in the following image
[image]

And this array returns error in map function. Do you have any idea which part is wrong?

Comment: Your reduce method is producing an object, which doesn't have a `.map()` method. Where are you trying to use `.map()`?

Comment: Is there a way to get result as array from reduce method?

Comment: Yes, there is, but the approach will be different depending on what result you're after.

Comment: you can use `Object.values(grouped)` and then use `.map()` but it depends on what you need